# Random blank screenshot using chrome-remote-interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am following the tutorial here on my Macbook Pro 10.12.5:

https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a

Below is my code:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const file = require('fs');

// CLI Args
const url = argv.url || 'https://www.google.com';
const format = argv.format === 'jpeg' ? 'jpeg' : 'png';
const viewportWidth = argv.viewportWidth || 1440;
const viewportHeight = argv.viewportHeight || 900;
const delay = argv.delay || 0;
const userAgent = argv.userAgent;
const fullPage = argv.full;

// Start the Chrome Debugging Protocol
CDP(async function(client) {
  // Extract used DevTools domains.
  const {DOM, Emulation, Network, Page, Runtime} = client;

  // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
  await Page.enable();
  await DOM.enable();
  await Network.enable();

  // If user agent override was specified, pass to Network domain
  if (userAgent) {
    await Network.setUserAgentOverride({userAgent});
  }

  // Set up viewport resolution, etc.
  const deviceMetrics = {
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
    deviceScaleFactor: 0,
    mobile: false,
    fitWindow: false,
  };
  await Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(deviceMetrics);
  await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight});

  // Navigate to target page
  await Page.navigate({url});

  // Wait for page load event to take screenshot
  Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
    // If the `full` CLI option was passed, we need to measure the height of
    // the rendered page and use Emulation.setVisibleSize
    if (fullPage) {
      const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();
      const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
        selector: 'body',
        nodeId: documentNodeId,
      });
      const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

      console.log(viewportWidth);
      console.log(height);
      await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: height});
      // This forceViewport call ensures that content outside the viewport is
      // rendered, otherwise it shows up as grey. Possibly a bug?
      // await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});
    }

    setTimeout(async function() {
      const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({format});
      const buffer = new Buffer(screenshot.data, 'base64');
      file.writeFile('output.png', buffer, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Screenshot saved');
        }
        client.close();
      });
    }, delay);
  });
}).on('error', err => {
  console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
});
```

Here is my versions of everything:

- "chrome-launcher": "^0.4.0"
- "chrome-remote-interface": "^0.24.3"
- "minimist": "^1.2.0"
- Google Chrome 62.0.3181.0 canary

My screenshot output.png is blank (7KB) and it seem to happen randomly few days ago but now pretty much constantly blank. Note that I had to comment out `// await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});` because of error `(node:1304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Emulation.forceViewport is not a function`

This is what happened when I ran:

```
$ node autoscreenshot.js --full
1440
900
Screenshot saved
```

So it does set the screen and everything but blank screenshot.

**THE ONLY WAY TO MAKE SCREENSHOT WORK** consistently is to use code below:

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const file = require('fs');

(async function() {
  async function launchChrome() {
    return await chromeLauncher.launch({
      chromeFlags: [
        '--disable-gpu'
        // '--headless'
      ]
    });
  }
  const chrome = await launchChrome();
  const protocol = await CDP({
    port: chrome.port
  });

  const {
    DOM,
    Network,
    Page,
    Emulation,
    Runtime
  } = protocol;
  await Promise.all([Network.enable(), Page.enable(), Runtime.enable(), DOM.enable()]);

  await Page.navigate({
    url: 'https://www.yahoo.com/'
  });

  Page.loadEventFired(async() => {

    console.log('Start Page.loadEventFired');

    const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();

    console.log('Start DOM.querySelector');
    const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
      selector: 'body',
      nodeId: documentNodeId
    });

    console.log('Start DOM.getBoxModel');
    const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

    console.log('height=' + height);

    console.log('Start Emulation.setVisibleSize');
    await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: 735, height: height});

    console.log('Start Page.captureScreenshot');
    const ss = await Page.captureScreenshot({format: 'png', fromSurface: true});

    console.log('Start file.writeFile');
    file.writeFile('output.png', ss.data, 'base64', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    protocol.close();
    chrome.kill(); 
  });

})();
```

Note that now I am using `chrome-launcher` but also remove `headless`. So it will popup the browser window. BUT it worked and took screenshot.

**So my questions:**

1. Is this just a bug in Canary 62 on Mac OSX Sierra?
2. If not, how to fix this so headless method works for screenshot?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried 2 more things and had success:

1. If I use Chrome 60 (stable) on Mac, it works and I can do screenshot headless.
2. If I use Chrome 60 (beta) on Ubuntu, it works as well for headless.

So the only case this doesn't work is **Canary 62 headless** since Canary 62 with the browser does work fine. Very strange indeed.